# how to return a unique set of characters within a field (SQL)?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Basically i am trying to return any fields within the tag column that contain up_ up1_ up2_ up3, up4_.

the problem i'm facing is  i only want to show these tags and not the others.

The field contains a mixture of characters on each row so i'm finding it difficult to use a CASE statement substr.

I've been able to return the entire field using this sql:

```
select tags
from products
where tags like '%up_%'
   or tags like '%Up*_%'
```

any ideas?

Many thanks,
Jonathon

EDIT
data within the column:

```
almost gone, 
Autumn/Winter, 
BEIGE
Coats Jackets
Cream, Gender_Female
ISAWITFIRST.com 
Neutrals 
Pcat-Coats & Jackets
S
Sale
SALE:New In Coats & Jackets
Sale:SALE:New In Clothing
Scat-Coat 
Up1_Cup-Detail-Sheer-Panel-Bodysuit-Cream-Jl33334
Up_High-Waisted-Skinny-Trousers-White-Jl34117
```

I want to be able to return only the UP1_ and Up_ tags. and want to remove the rest..

EDIT 2

This column is populated by an external site

Comment: Add some sample table data and also the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) And take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "only want to show these tags and not the others." Do you want to skip all chars except the tags?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. And a SQL `case` is an _expression_, not a statement.

Comment: @jarlh OP is talking about fields _in_ a column (`tags`). OP: Is this perhaps some json column? Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: im using Athena to query data within an S3 bucket

Comment: instead of the tags showing:


almost gone, Autumn/Winter, BEIGE, Coats Jackets, Cream, Gender_Female, ISAWITFIRST.com, Neutrals, Pcat-Coats & Jackets, S, Sale, SALE:New In Coats & Jackets, Sale:SALE:New In Clothing, Scat-Coat, Up1_Cup-Detail-Sheer-Panel-Bodysuit-Cream-Jl33334, Up_High-Waisted-Skinny-Trousers-White-Jl34117

I would like the column to show:
Up1_Cup-Detail-Sheer-Panel-Bodysuit-Cream-Jl33334, Up_High-Waisted-Skinny-Trousers-White-Jl34117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **PostgreSQL** for instance, you could go with the following:

```
select substring(tags from '[Uu]p[0-9]?_')
from products
where tags like '%up_%'
   or tags like '%Up*_%'
```

Please adjust the regular expression in the first line to your exact needs.

For other DB-Systems, swap the substring function for one of the following:

For **TSQL**, have a look at the "patindex"-function.
For **Athena**, consider the REGEXP_SUBSTR function, as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

Comment: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar(12)) for function substr. Expected: substr(varchar(x), bigint, bigint) , substr(varchar(x), bigint) , substr(char(x), bigint, bigint) , substr(char(x), bigint)

Comment: The above is the error i receive, i've tried the substr as well.

Comment: dont have athena to try it out, but i think it should be `REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, '[Uu]p[0-9]?_')`

Comment: unfortunately that expression is a redshift term which im not using. thanks for the help though.

Comment: Oh damn.. Do you have any function in Athena, that matches regexes? Maybe you can cobble something together, using substring and an index from some regex match function?

Comment: nope just the standard split_part, substr() but it does't function like that regexes one. 

Thanks for your help but I've managed to manipulate the data within python instead!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a way!